# How can I block spike traps on the PC?

Tags: pc, ryse-son-of-rome

I'm at a point in the game where I'm stuck. I keep getting killed by a spike trap.

The game game me some information earlier on how to block it, but the information doesn't come again. I might have read it wrong. If I remember correctly, we're supposed to wait for the color to change, then hit the button corresponding to the color.

The spike trap flashes yellow, so I believe I'm supposed to press the right mouse button (shield action).

I tried waiting for the color to change to yellow and then hitting the button. I still got killed.

I tried spamming the right mouse button the moment the spike trap starts moving (before it turns yellow) right until it hits me. I still got killed.

I tried pressing and holding the right mouse button. I still got killed.

How do I overcome this spike trap? I died 30 times to it already, so I find it hard to believe its just bad timing on my part.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Watching some let's play videos of the game, the instructions for traps says

> {Button} to Deflect.
>   To defeat traps, time your deflection to occur in the colored timing window, similar to executions.

The [manual](http://www.rysegame.com/manual/) states that the default button for deflection is space when playing with keyboard and mouse.

Answer (score -1):

After trying 50 times myself, it's the middle mouse button and not the right mouse button (shield bash).